# SharePoint 2013 Workflow: How to create or reassign a task when document approval fails

Tags: designer-workflow

I am creating a task management application within SharePoint. When a user enters some data into a list, a workflow on that list creates a document within a document library. The workflow then creates a task assigned to that user, requiring him to complete certain fields within the document.

Once the user marks that task as complete, the document is then put through an approval process. If the document is rejected, I want the workflow to loop back round and start again, creating a new task for the user.

There doesn't seem to be a way in SharePoint to loop back to previous stages within a workflow, so what is the best way to achieve this? I thought I could just start a new iteration of the workflow, but of course I can only start 2010 workflows from inside a 2013 workflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create one workflow variable and save your last stage to workflow variable. When user reject workflow on reject set workflow  Go To "workflow variable" that store last stage. or you can store stage where you want to send workflow on reject.

please refer below image.In workflow 2013 "Transition to stage" you will find "Go To"

[image: PSD 2013 workflow]

Comment: I don't have that option on the Go To command - I only have the named stages, plus End of Workflow. There doesn't seem to be a dynamic option using workflow variables.